# How do i generate a customer id while doing transaction Braintree

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, braintree

My goal is to generate a transaction sale while generating the customer id so that I could store the customer id to the database

The reason why i need customer id is because so that the same user doesn't need to enter his credit/debit card again

```
const gateway = braintree.connect({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: '',
  publicKey: '',
  privateKey: ''
});

app.post('/payment', (req, res, next) => {

  gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: req.body.amount,
    paymentMethodNonce: req.body.nonce,
    options: {
      submitForSettlement: true
    }
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err)

    }
    if (result.success) {
      console.log('Transaction ID: ' + result.transaction.id);
      res.json({
        transactionId: result.transaction.id
      })
    } else {
      console.error(result.message);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

One option would be to use the [`storeInVaultOnSuccess`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#options.store_in_vault_on_success) flag. If the transaction is successful, then the payment method will be stored in your Braintree Vault.

If you also pass in a [`customerId`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#customer_id) for an existing record in your Braintree Vault, then the resulting stored payment method will be associated with that customer. Otherwise, a new customer record will be created for the payment method. You can access the new customer ID on the result object like this:

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  paymentMethodNonce: "fake-valid-nonce",
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true,
    storeInVaultOnSuccess: true
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    // handle err
  }

  if (result.success) {
    console.log('Transaction ID: ' + result.transaction.id);
    console.log('Customer ID: ' + result.transaction.customer.id);
  } else {
    console.error(result.message);
  }
});
```